# Convert Json WrappedArray to String using spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm working on a zeppelin notebook and try to load data from a table using sql. 
In the table, each row has one column which is a JSON blob. For example,  `[{'timestamp':12345,'value':10},{'timestamp':12346,'value':11},{'timestamp':12347,'value':12}]`

I want to select the JSON blob as a string, like the original string. But spark automatically load it as a WrappedArray.

It seems that I have to write a UDF to convert the WrappedArray to a string. The following is my code.

I first define a Scala function and then register the function. And then use the registered function on the column.

```
val unwraparr = udf ((x: WrappedArray[(Int, Int)]) => x.map { case Row(val1: String) =>  + "," + val2 })
sqlContext.udf.register("fwa", unwraparr)
```

It doesn't work. I would really appreciate if anyone can help.

The following is the schema of the part I'm working on. There will be many amount and timeStamp pairs.

```
-- targetColumn: array (nullable = true)
    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
    |    |-- timeStamp: string (nullable = true)
```

UPDATE:
I come up with the following code:

```
val f = (x: Seq[Row]) => x.map { case Row(val1: Long, val2: String) => x.mkString("+") }
```

I need it to concat the objects/struct/row (not sure how to call the struct) to a single string.

Comment: can you update with `schema` of the `dataframe`? just copy paste the output of `dataframe.printSchema()`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan It's updated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please update the desired output.

Comment: @AnkushSingh Designed output is: {'timestamp':12345,'value':10},{'timestamp':12346,'value':11},{'timestamp':12347,'value':12}. Right now, the column shown in zipplin is WrappedArray([10, 12345],[11,12346],[12,12347]). The column is parsed automatically, but I want the original json string.

Comment: @Ryan please see my updated answer below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loaded data as `dataframe`/`dataset` in `spark` is as below with `schema` as

```
+------------------------------------+
|targetColumn                        |
+------------------------------------+
|[[12345,10], [12346,11], [12347,12]]|
|[[12345,10], [12346,11], [12347,12]]|
+------------------------------------+

root
 |-- targetColumn: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- timeStamp: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

Then you can write the `dataframe` as `json` to a temporary json file and read it as text file and parse the `String line` and convert it to `dataframe` as below (`/home/testing/test.json`  is the temporary `json` file location)

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("/home/testing/test.json")

val data = sc.textFile("/home/testing/test.json")

val rowRdd = data.map(jsonLine => Row(jsonLine.split(":\\[")(1).replace("]}", "")))
val stringDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, StructType(Array(StructField("targetColumn", StringType, true))))
```

Which should leave you with following `dataframe` and `schema`

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|targetColumn                                                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"timeStamp":"12345","value":10},{"timeStamp":"12346","value":11},{"timeStamp":"12347","value":12}|
|{"timeStamp":"12345","value":10},{"timeStamp":"12346","value":11},{"timeStamp":"12347","value":12}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- targetColumn: string (nullable = true)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**read initially as text not dataframe**

You can use my second phase of answer i.e. reading from json file and parsing, into your first phase of getting dataframe.